# Text (from file) to running program

Tags: editors, stdin, kate

I have degenerative bone disease in my hands and would like to make YouTube videos that look like I am typing in a text editor such as Sublime or Kate (KDE).

How can I make a ***text editor receive a text file of input through stdin while it is running*** (typing effect) - perhaps using sockets, piping, process id, etc?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a terminal based text editor such as, `vi`, `jed`, `joe` (or `vim`/`emacs`/`xemacs` though those also have GUI versions), you can use things like `expect`, `zsh`'s `zpty`, `screen` or `tmux` to simulate input (or `scriptreplay` to replay a captured `script` session).

For X11 text editors (though would also work for terminal editors running in a X11 terminal emulator), you can use `xdotool` or `xte` (from `xautomation`) to simulate key press and release events.

`xdotool` has the `keydown`, `keyup` subcommands to send the corresponding X11 events to a window, or `key` to combine both in sequence, and `type` to send the sequence of key press+release events to generate some text.

```
xdotool type --delay 300 $'test\n'
```

Simulates <kbd>t</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>t</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> key press+release with 300 milliseconds in between them.

With `xte`, you can achieve the same with:

```
xte << 'EOF'
key t
usleep 300000
key e
usleep 300000
key s
usleep 300000
key t
usleep 300000
key Return
EOF
```

See their respective man pages for details.